# What are other values permitted in type attribute of <field name="arch" type="xml"> in Odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo

When we create form / tree views, we enter the following code snippet.

```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
```

What are other values/options that we can enter in type attribute?

Comment: Interesting question which i had myself some years ago, too, but never really looked into it. Maybe some really old school tinyERP developer can answer that question :-)